# Как заставить растянуться на всю оставшуюся ширину последний элемент списка?

Tags: css

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
.menu li a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
ins {
    text-decoration: none;
}
del {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
.navigation {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    display: table;
    position: relative;

}
.menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table-row;
}
.item {
    display: table-cell;
    float: left;
    background: yellow;
    outline: 1px solid lightgray;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 2.5;
    text-align: center;
}
.first {
    width: 20em;
}
.second {
    width: 30%;
}
.third {
    width: 200px;
}
.fourth {
    
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li class="item first"><a href="#">First</a></li>
        <li class="item second"><a href="#">Second</a></li>
        <li class="item third"><a href="#">Third</a></li>
        <li class="item fourth"><a href="#">Fourth</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.navigation {
    width: 100wh;
}

ul li:last-child {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Ещё вариант использовать `calc()`, типа `width: calc(20em - 30% - 200px);`. Правда, я не очень помню правила использования этой функции и не уверен, что она отработает с величинами в разных единицах измерения.

Comment: убрал float: left, помогло ))

Comment: уууп-с:) я, честно говоря, не посмотрел код внимательно перед тем, как писать ответ. Но мой способ тоже должен работать, в теории)

Answer (score 2):

Я так понимаю, что Вы создаете горизонтальное меню?

Тогда предложу такой вариант:

```
ul.menu {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
ul.menu>li {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Таким образом браузер видит все меню как таблицу, а ее элементы - ячейки таблицы.

Замечание: в Вашем примере у `.item` написано `float: left;` - придется убрать :)

Comment: у _item_ уже стоит _display: table-cell;_, а у меню - _display: table-row;_

Comment: да, совершенно верно

Comment: Да, но `float: left;` в моем примере нет :):):):) Уберите `float: left;` из `.item`

Answer (score 1):

Или вот так сделать меню:

```
.menu {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.menu li {
  flex: auto;
  background: #DC851F;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 1px;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

[Ссылка на пример.](http://codepen.io/NeedHate/pen/vNqBvb)